# Does sqlite support JOIN in DELETE clause?

Tags: sqlite

In general, MySQL supports JOIN clause for deletion query.
Example - 
DELETE w
FROM WorkRecord2 w
INNER JOIN Employee e
  ON EmployeeRun=EmployeeNo
WHERE Company = '1' AND Date = '2013-05-06'

Does sqlite supports the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite does not support the join construct which MySQL does.  However, you may still rephrase your query using a correlated subquery, e.g.

```
DELETE
FROM WorkRecord2 w
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Employee e
              WHERE w.EmployeeRun = e.EmployeeNo AND e.Company = '1') AND
    Date = '2013-05-06';
```